# 4 Digit 7 segment display LED missing one light (on all four digits)

Tags: led, pcb, soldering, lcd, 7segmentdisplay

Hi I ordered online a voltage meter and got this tiny cute little fast refreshing pretty darn precise reliable meter. HOWEVER I am missing on all four digits the left lower vertical light piece. What could be causing this? the solder joins look okay so where exactly must I check to fix this myself?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is the image or any link to your voltage meter?

Comment: Are you able to provide a higher res image and/or identify the IC?

Comment: CZAbhinav BenG Ive added the two large photos its a tiny tiny motherboard so this is as close as I could get!

Comment: Knock it out moderators al of us tech users over here are trying to solve this electrical problem which is often happening, so better get a good open knowledge going here about how these things work and how to fix them, cut it out with your off-topic moderation and leave this question as well as its handy answers alone!

Comment: @Sam You've been here for four years. Look around. What happens to questions like "This gadget I bought on eBay doesn't work. Why?" when there is no schematic or any kind of documentation present? -1 for the attitude. Further, how do you call one instance "often happening?"

Comment: @Matt upon contacting the seller he informed me these things are common, I assume most buyers search some and upon finding nothing they just... give up. Well I didn't give up and posted a question including photos and described as much info as I had. If you find my attitude lazy and worth -1 so be it. Maybe others find this a good question. My attitute? I am proud of my 1 gold medal even though (read especially) for having only 250 reputation mate! Cheers and hope I get this LCD fixed in which case I will post back my findings and new photos over here!

Answer (score 4):

One of the display segment lines (with a resistor) is broken somewhere between the die and the display insides. Chances are its crummy soldering by the manufacturer, but it could be a bad chip or display or resistor. That will cause segment E to be off on all digits.

Look at the soldering of the lines on either side of the array of 8 resistors and to the resistors themselves. In particular look at the one highlighted below:

[image]

Edit: I've shown the possible places (blue arrows) where a solder joint could be bad, based on the usual pinout for such an LED display, but I think I see the problem- there appears to be a cut in the trace (circled in red). The solder joints don't look obviously bad. If it is a break (look at it under a microscope or magnifier) you can scrape the solder mask off gently with a knife and bridge the gap with a bit of very thin wire and solder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see my two extra new photos of the backside of the motherboard of the 7 segment LED lcd. Can you draw with arrows which ones I should resolder??

Answer (score 3):

It is seem there is a broken line between the controller pin (microcontroller/microprocessor/7-segmen driver IC) and the e-pin of the seven segment. You need to trace from seven segment to the controller with multimeter (ohm-meter) to find the broken pcb track/soldering or bad resistor.

[image]

Comment: Would that be the case with a 4x 7 segment?

Comment: I think so. Typical multiple seven segments circuit uses multiplexing and share same a~g and dot bus

Comment: Duh. brain freeze. of course you are right. and the fact it affects all of them implies the break will be between the controller and the 1st 7 seg.

Comment: I see, so probably only ONE (1) connection is incomplete???

Comment: Yes. but it will be between the first 7seg and the 7seg driver so that narrows it down a bit.